# Why the d-pad right key doesn't work with SUPER+CTRL while the numpad 6 key does?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I can't use SUPER+CTRL+Right to dock a window to the right half of the window but it works fine with the left key and when using the numpad button 6. it's important for me to be able to use the d-pad because my desktop keyboard doesn't have a numpad.

Any one knows what's causing this?

Thank you.